# tiny implementation of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, each

1) I have a task to implement jQuery on Javascript.
But for some reason my method each doesn't work.
For example when i write

```
$('.a').each(function (index) {$(this).append('<b>' + index + '</b>')})
```

it returns

DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[object Object]' is not a valid selector.

also I can't use `this.each` inside of other functions. For example if I would have used each instead of `forEach` inside append it would have not worked.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  function $(selector) {
    if (this instanceof $) return this.search(selector)
      return new $(selector);
  }
  $.prototype = {
    constructor: $,
    length: 0,

    search: function(selector) {
      var that=this;
      var elems=Array.prototype.slice
          .call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
      elems.forEach(function(x,i){that[i]=x;});
      this.length = elems.length;
      return this;
    },

    append: function(text) {
      if (text instanceof $) {
        this[0].appendChild(text[0]);
        for(var i = 1; i < this.length-1; i++) {
          var p = text[0].cloneNode(true);
          this[i].appendChild(p);
        }
      } else Array.prototype.slice
          .call(this).forEach(function(x){
              x.innerHTML  =  x.innerHTML  +  text;
          });

      return this;
    },  

    each: function(callback){
      for (var i=0;i<this.length;i++){
        this[i]=callback.call(this,this[i])
      };
      return this;
    },

  }
  window.$ = $;
}());
```

Comment: *"I have a task to implement jQuery on Javascript."* Er....jQuery ***is*** implemented "on" (in) JavaScript.

Comment: it is working on fiddle here is  
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n4aspu8p/)

Comment: By the way FYI using the `.each()` method on a selector which is selecting an `#id` (which is a single element) doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: ok, i've corrected to use it for class. but the sence is the same. i can not use $(this) and this.each doesn,t work in other methods anyway..

Comment: @ozil: You're using the real jQuery in that. The OP is trying to *reimplement* jQuery, (starting) with the code in the question.

Answer (score 5):

> For example when i write
>
> ```
> $('#id').each(function (index) {$(this).html('<b>' + index + '</b>')})
> ```
>
> it returns
>
> DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[object Object]' is not a valid selector.

You're doing `$(this)` inside your `each` callback. So that calls `$` with `this` set to the DOM element, which is not `instanceof $`, and so you call `new $(selector)` passing the DOM element. That ends up calling `this.search(selector)` where, again, `selector` is the DOM element. Then you call `querySelectorAll(selector)`. QSA accepts strings, not DOM elements, and so the element gets converted to the string `"[object Object]"` (or on some engines it'll be `"[object HTMLElement]"`), and fails.

You can diagnose these errors by walking through the code statement-by-statement using the debugger built into your browser. If you're going to reimplement jQuery for some reason, you'll need to get in the habit of doing exactly that: Using the debugger heavily, identifying what's wrong, and fixing it.

In this case, for instance, you'll want to detect that `selector` is not a string and handle that, e.g. something vaguely like this:

```
search: function(selector) {
  var that=this, elems;
  if (typeof selector === "string") {
    elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
    elems.forEach(function(x,i){that[i]=x;});
    this.length = elems.length;
  } else {
    this[0] = selector;
    this.length = 1;
  }
  return this;
},
```

But there will be lots and lots of other things you'll run into beyond that, which you'll need your debugger for.

Comment: I can not understand why when i'm going outside of an append function this looks ok, but next step it comes to each function and now this[0] is undefined.

Comment: I understood! my each function wasn't written right!

Comment: I have 1 question yet! When i write .children() function i want 'this' to be changed,and to return it. Am i right when i delete all properties: 0,1,2... till length in 'this' and then replace them with new ones which are children of this?
Or there is more elegant method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your usecase but to implement all edge cases would be a bit more complicated:

```
(function() {
  function $(selector) {
    if (!(this instanceof $)){//forgot new
      return new $(selector);
    }
    if(typeof selector === 'string'){ 
      return this.search(selector);
    }
    //assuming selector is a dom object
    this[0]=selector;
    this.length=1;
  }
  $.prototype = {
    constructor: $,
    length: 0,

    search: function(selector) {
      var that=this;
      var elems=Array.prototype.slice
          .call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
      elems.forEach(function(x,i){that[i]=x;});
      this.length = elems.length;
      return this;
    },
    append: function(text) {
      if (text instanceof $) {
        this[0].appendChild(text[0]);
        for(var i = 1; i < this.length-1; i++) {
          var p = text[0].cloneNode(true);
          this[i].appendChild(p);
        }
      } else {
           this.each(function(x){
              this.innerHTML  =  this.innerHTML  +  text;
          });
      }
      return this;
    },  
    // callback is called with the invoking object to be the dom element
    each: function(callback){
      for (var i=0;i<this.length;i++){
        this[i]=callback.call(this[i],i);
      };
      return this;
    },

  }
  window.$ = $;
}());
$('.a').each(function (index) {return $(this).append('<b>' + index + '</b>')})
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, but also each function should be changed so that just call callback but not to assign it to this[i]